# PHP syntax error issue (with a testcase)

Tags: php, configuration

Could someone give me a pointer on what could be wrong here:

File f1.php:

```
<?php

include('f2.php');
```

File f2:

```
<?php
echo "HERE";
```

Error reported:

```
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in f1.php on line 4`
```

- Using php-fpm 5.4 on nginx 1.2.6.
- Files have no BOM marker.
- The server has no hardware issues.

It's probabbly a configuration issue, but i just can't seem to figure it out.

I've asked this question a few minutes ago, but got instantly closed as too localized as I was referencing a situation in my project and not a specific situation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651673/strange-php-syntax-error-issue)

UPDATE: Obviously not related to nginx ... same error if executed in cli

Comment: Do you have any php configuration that is auto prepending a file to all requests?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in f1.php on line 4 -- f1.php only has 3 lines, but errors on line 4?

Comment: @user2023235: the f1 has 4 lines, f2 has 3 lines

Comment: @Jure Kajzer what is on line 4 of f1.php.  Your code sample only has 3 lines

Comment: @datasage: no, noprepending

Comment: @user2023235: sorry ... f1 has 3 lines ... so there's nothing on 4th line what i've posted is all there is in those two files

Comment: is that the whole files shown?

Comment: @pivotnig: yes that is the whole file

Comment: Cannot reproduce: Works fine here. Like the others I must assume, that you have missed to tell use something. Also an IDE may help ;)

Comment: @Jure Kajzer Im no php expert, but dont you need to close the <?php at the end of the file with ?>

Comment: @KingCrunch (and all others) i guess you didn't read the post or just didn't get the point ... it's a config issue (with either php or system in general) ... the code is fine, it works for me too on an another server ... i don't see what difference would it make for this testcase if i used Eclipse or Geany or vi or a punch-card for that matter.

Comment: @JureKajzer Which config setting do you mean? Or are you simply guessing? Because I don't know _any_ setting, that will make this code invalid and inserts arbitrary characters at arbitrary locations ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch that's exactly what i'm asking ... the php has been built from source on this system so i'm **guessing** it has to do with the way the php is started or cofigured (php.ini or php-fpm.conf or env) but i ran out of ideas what that might be.<br />
I've tried running php interactivly (-a) and including f2.php from there and i get the same error. if i load f2.php with file_get_contents and dump the byte array i see no additional chars that would explain the issue. No BOM or any other magic at the beginning of the file, line endings are all newline only, no garbage in between ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems i've solved it ...

Short story:
Recompiled PHP with `--enable-zend-multibyte`.

Long story:
I tried everything imaginable ... checked source files byte-by-byte and there were no issues to be found. I've tried getting file contents inside php and echoing byte array from insidde php and in this case too, no issues to be found.
I've tried recompiling php with debugging symbols, but the process finished with 0377 and gdb had nothing useful to offer.

No matter what i did, uppon hitting an include statement (or variants of it) i got the syntax error on line past last of the included file.

I would expect the files having BOM (as suggested by almost everyone i've asked). So i thought it **had to be** something with how php was being run and tried changing environment variables (like LC_* vars) but again no results.

So i the end i had an add-configure-option-and-recompile-php session ... not sure exactly why as all of the scripts contain no multibyte chars and as stated before no BOM marker, but after recompiling PHP with `--enable-zend-multibyte`, the code started to work as expected.

**Thanks to all for suggestions.**

Comment: that's a bit late to ask now, but have you tried to save your .php files with the windows notepad in ascii mode only? that would have cleaned every multibyte char inside of them

Comment: @link: as i've said the files have been checked with a hex editor, byte by byte, there were no multibyte chars in the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using APC probabily you don't have updated the previous byte code.

Try `apc_clear_cache();`